# How do I get Vaadin to load a JS file in UTF-8 using the JavaScript annotation?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, d3.js, vaadin7

I'm trying to use Vaadin with d3.js. If I use d3.js with some custom JavaScript in a handwritten HTML file, I have to include d3.js in utf-8 (because the author decided it'd be a good idea to use all sorts of funky characters throughout his code to represent things like pi):

```
<script src="d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Simple enough. But if I use it with this custom Vaadin widget, I have to use Vaadin's JavaScript notation:

```
@JavaScript({"myscript.js","d3.js",})
```

Which again is simple enough for myscript.js, but it does not interpret d3.js as utf-8, and so I ultimately get `illegal character` errors when I load the page with all this stuff in my browser.

Is there a way to get Vaadin's JavaScript annotation to decode d3.js the way it requires?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the encoding in the annotation, but I think UTF-8 should be the default. JavaScript follows the page encoding. Check that the page you have the application has something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Alternatively this might be a server problem. Some servers do not properly serve text files (including JS) using the encoding they are on the filesystem (or the file is not UTF-8 at all). Try to load the d3.js JavaScript file separately and the HTTP headers for UTF-8 and see that the content looks ok.